# Add the installation prefix of "Qt5UiTools" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: linux, cmake, qt5, ubuntu-14.04, gnu-make

**I am using cmake version 3.2.2, as it is the requirement of code**
I am trying to build [MikTex source code](http://miktex.org/howto/build-unx) but am getting different errors that i don't know about on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
When i run `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"` command from the directory of source code folder "miktex-2.9-2015-12-22" i get following error:

> CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:26 (find_package):
>     Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5UiTools" with
>     any of the following names:

```
Qt5UiToolsConfig.cmake
qt5uitools-config.cmake
```

> Add the installation prefix of "Qt5UiTools" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>     "Qt5UiTools_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
>     "Qt5UiTools" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
>     been installed.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:466 (find_package)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing a package.
The package containing 'Qt5UiToolsConfig.cmake' is 'qttools5-dev'

Comment: Yeah, by adding this package this issue is resolved and another error has originated that is: -- checking for module 'botan-1.10'
--   package 'botan-1.10' not found. CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:340 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:502 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  cmake/modules/FindBOTAN110.cmake:3 (pkg_check_modules)
  CMakeLists.txt:470 (find_package)

Comment: You are missing 'libbotan1.10-dev'...
But you will only encounter more errors since miktex seems to be Windows only.

Comment: okay i have installed it using sudo apt-get install libbotan1.10-dev. That's teasing its just keep me asking for packages :/

Comment: Well even if you manage to install all required packages you will only get compilation errors which are definitely harder to fix

Comment: At last compilation started.. let' see :)

Comment: stopped with an error after running executing make command :P c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=gnu++14’

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 g++ is quite old

Comment: wows,. great it seems like you have great information about compilation stuff ... impressive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99696/discussion-between-david-marquant-and-nomi).